# How to study for cyber security basic level exam?

Tags: professional-education

I have a basic level exam on cyber security, so I was wondering what I should read and learn for the exam. I would appreciate it if you would help me find some study materials to work with.

Comment: Which exam? Basic level cybersecurity means little, as that ranges from the OSCP, to Testout Security Pro, to Security+, to GSEC, to the CEH, and so on and so forth. The last thing I would want to do is waste your time.

Comment: Also, welcome to the forum!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to studying for any exam is to find the exam outline. These are the topic areas that are to be covered in the exam. Sometimes known as the Common Body of Knowledge (CBK) or Domains.

Failing that buy a book on the exam and good luck. Without knowning the exam I can't be anymore detailed.

Comment: the problem is in that thing i dont know the outline of the exam ,they dont give it...

Comment: We can't know more than you about your own exam, however much we might like to. We need either a name of the exam or an outline of the topic before we can provide study materials.

Comment: i understand that no problem.but i am also helpless.